# How secure is CryptoCat

Tags: encryption

Is CryptoCat secure? It is hard for me to determine if a program is secure or not. Let's compare them both to the programs called

- Wire
- Ricochet
- WhatsApp

and all the other services which provide e2e encryption.

Comment: `and all the other services which provide e2e encryption.` this is not a software comparison website and there is endless amount of services using E2E encryption.

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of CryptoCat. The web application was available between 2011 and 2016. The new desktop version was available from 2016. Both were developed by the same developer, Nadim Kobeissi.

In the old web application, [a number of vulnerabilities were found](https://tobtu.com/decryptocat.php). This leads some people to believe that the developer is not adequately skilled to develop secure applications, and thus the new CryptoCat will also not be secure.

I don't think the new version of CryptoCat has received an independent security audit, so little is known about the security of it.

Different systems have different security trade-offs, but not necessary better or worse. For example, when you use WhatsApp you use a [audited encryption protocol](https://www.cyberscoop.com/signal-security-audit-encryption-facebook-messenger-whatsapp/), but Facebook (and U.S. authorities) will know who you contacted. It's hard to say whether a system is "more secure" than some other system.